# Why is the element type in the list data_from.scenes changing to another type?

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files

I have the following script. What exactly is happening in the background, why does the element type in `data_from.scenes[0]` change from `class 'str'` to `class 'bpy.types.Scene'`. [From this thread I quote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187707):

> It's just a special case of reusing a variable, which is a bad idea - mainly because it makes it hard to understand what a variable contains at any given point in the program flow. See e.g. [Should I reuse variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115520/should-i-reuse-variables)

```
import bpy

filepath = "/path/to/blend/file.blend"

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.scenes = data_from.scenes
    print("T1:", type(data_from.scenes[0])) # prints class 'str'

print("T2:", type(data_from.scenes[0])) # prints class 'bpy.types.Scene'
```

The sudden change in data type confused me.

Comment: It doesn't really surprise me much, `with` makes it an inner scope than the global scope, and you're accessing `data_from` when this scope has been closed, which is not prevented by python, but can lead to funky behaviour, because you don't have a say in what happens when the `with` scope closes. Basically it's a wrapper like python decorators that executes some arbitrary code written elsewhere when its scope finishes.

Comment: @Gorgious hey that's actually a very good point, i didn't realize it indeed is out of scope and python didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly that happens: "The sudden change in data type"

Sybren explains it a bit in his "scripting for artists" series (asset linking around 8:40 https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists/5eabe54d521eafd0953f6d45/).
Ok, not really explains, but Blender does this "magic" -> it exchanges the value from a string list to a collection. So Blender assigns just a new value to this variable. That's all.